# Optional field with regex pattern shouldn't be marked as invalid when empty, foundation version 5.3.3

Tags: zurb-foundation

Foundation abide adds "data-invalid" attribute to input when submitting form with empty field with regex validation pattern.

```
<input id="IBAN" name="IBAN" pattern="(\w{2}\d{26})?" type="text" value="" />
```

How to set up abide to ignore regex validation when field is optional, not required and empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that [abide](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/abide.html) doesn't like your pattern/regular expression, specifically the question mark.

I think what you are trying to validate is a string that includes at least two alphanumeric characters and the underscore being case insensitive, `\w{2}`, followed by at least twenty-six digits, `\d{26}`.

If that is the case then I believe that just using `<input id="IBAN" name="IBAN" type="text" pattern="(\w{2}\d{26})">` or `<input id="IBAN" name="IBAN" type="text" pattern="\w{2}\d{26}">` would work.

I also created a [codepen](http://codepen.io/adam-huffman/full/8c2773c7d26f2330391dfb61624efa36/) that demonstrates the two ways to set up abide patterns if it helps.

If that's not what you are wanting the regular expression to do or if I am on the wrong track let me know.

Thanks,